# Ubislate 7ci drivers to list the device using adb devices

Tags: android, adb, device-driver

I connected my Ubislate 7ci device with android SDK installed on windows.This particular device is not getting listed when i use "adb devices" command.I googled for Ubislate drivers but couldn't find.
I Hope most of you guys are successful in getting the device detected by adb.Pls let me know how to get Ubislate 7ci detected by adb.

Thanks.

Comment: Does it get properly recognized in the device manager? Is the device functional (no exclamation marks)?

Answer (score 1):

If your manufacturer doesnt provide a driver, try using a generic driver like the PDAnet driver. [This](http://www.topnotchtablets.com/installADBdriver) should help you out with that.

Answer (score 0):

Refer below link you can use common driver for all

http://developer.android.com/sdk/win-usb.html

http://developer.android.com/tools/extras/oem-usb.html#InstallingDriver

Answer (score 0):

The things mentioned in other answers works only for well recognized devices, but it doesn't work for all devices.

I also have faced same problem for one device and i also did these mentioned things but it dint help and also i had searched on internet but not found any solution.

So final Solution is to get the USB drivers from device vendor. you can only get the drivers from device manufacturer. so start proceeding with that, thats it.

hope it helps.